# jquery keeps animating up and doesn't stop in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-animate

I cant figure out why, chrome keeps animating up and up my menu tags (price tags).[site here](http://nagomedia.pl/index.php?id=1). It works every where else but in chrome it goes up and up....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid `em` here. It is a relative unit and may not give the desired results. Use an absolute unit like `px`. Also if you stop the animation it might change the heights of subsequent animations. Use absolute heights here at well instead of calculating them each time:

```
$('.main > .menu > img').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ top: '50px' }, 150);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ top: '60px' }, 150);
});
```

Comment: I don't know why but at first it goes way down and after that it work correctly..

Comment: Sorry I misread your CSS. You'll have to change those `top` values to actually match your page. `50px` should be `-60px` and `60px` should be `-50px`